# Excel process stuck in Task Manager

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

In Access I open an Excel file, read from it and close it. The Excel process does not go away from Task Manager.

I found the same problem [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/908ba72a-3293-4eb9-b80e-fd2e6e78e185/vba-close-excel-problem?forum=accessdev) but no solution that worked.

If I click the Reset button in the VB Editor, it goes away (or if I change anything in the code, which also causes the project to reset and gets rid of the unwanted Excel process).

I have the following class, called `clsTest`:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private xlFolder As String
Private xlFile As String
Private xlSheet As String
Private colShortURL As String
Private oXL As Excel.Application
Private oWB As Excel.Workbook
Private oWS As Excel.Worksheet
Private iLastRow As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "From class: Going through initialization inside class - constructor"
    xlFolder = "E:\COMH\Excel"
    xlFile = "Records v8z.xlsm"
    xlSheet = "comh"
    Set oXL = New Excel.Application
    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=(xlFolder & "\" & xlFile), ReadOnly:=True)
    Set oWS = oWB.Sheets(xlSheet)
    iLastRow = oWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
End Sub

Public Property Get ShortURL() As String
    ShortURL = "Hello World " & iLastRow
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "From class: Going through the clean-up inside class - destructor"
    oWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set oWS = Nothing
    Set oWB = Nothing
    oXL.Quit
    Set oXL = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have the following Module to use above class:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestClass()
    Dim newExcel As clsTest
Try:
    On Error GoTo Catch
    Set newExcel = New clsTest
    Debug.Print "Class instantiated, all good"
    Debug.Print "ShortURL=" & newExcel.ShortURL
    GoTo Finally
Catch:
    Debug.Print "dealing with the error"
    Debug.Print Err.Description & " - " & Err.Number
Finally:
    Debug.Print "doing the finally stuff"
    Set newExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get the result I want:

```
From class: Going through initialization inside class - constructor
Class instantiated, all good
ShortURL=Hello World 2603
doing the finally stuff
From class: Going through the clean-up inside class - destructor
```

There are no errors but a process for Excel persists in Task Manager Processes tab.

Comment: If you place a `Debug.Print "finshed"` statement at the very **end** of the destructor, is it executed?

Comment: If you completely remove `on error` from your code - any change? I suspect it has somethind to do with the way VBA implements classes OR there is some other code in your app that isn't releasing the object. If there is no answer for this by this afternoon I'll try and repro .If I can't repro then it must be something else in your code not releasing references

Comment: Yes, it is executed, if I place the debug.print "finished" as asked. It will show in the immediate window as the last printed line.

Comment: I commented out all references to error and try-catch-finally labels from the module code, now it has only four lines of code (dim... set ... print .. set....), and the problem persists.

Comment: I also did the following test: made Excel visible upon its creation inside the class, and removed completely the Terminate procedure. Then, after I had run the code, everything worked fine but I had the Excel workbook open in front of me. I then closed the workbook and closed Excel manually. The Excel process still persists in Task Manager.

Comment: If I open Excel manually, then open the file Records v8z.xlsm manually, then close the file, then close Excel, I have no problem. Excel process vanishes from the Task Manager as expected.

Comment: I keep trying to figure out what's going on. Now I found that if I comment out (remove) the line iLastRow = oWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row from the class, the problem goes away. But then it means I cannot do nothing with the Excel file inside the class... useless class. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nice troubleshooting!

try changing the problematic line from

```
 iLastRow = oWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
```

to this (*you may need to go further and reference the range at the Application level, I can't remember this and can't test now*)

```
iLastRow = oWS.Range("A" & oWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
```

The likely issue is that you do not have a fully qualified reference, see [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/xl_doesnt_quit/#Cause)

Comment: You nailed it! Problem was solved. Thank you! I would never had guessed that, this issue was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, excel and other office apps didnt close completely from TaskManager because i was running **Fiddler** tool(for tracing the http requests since i mostly work on web applications).

If i **close or stop capturing on fiddler tool** then it exits from TaskManager properly.