# Multiple Excel Instances - No errors, but no changes from on macros

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-instances

Please refer to the following for the question:

```
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Set xlapp = GetObject(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\file - Map.xlsm").Application
Set mapbook = xlapp.Application.Workbooks("file - Map.xlsm")
Set map = mapbook.Worksheets("Map")
Debug.Print mapbook.FullName
Set databook = ActiveWorkbook
Set data = databook.Worksheets("Tables")
data.Activate
```

Originally, all sheets were in one workbook and everything worked splendidly. The macros would bounce between sheets and do its thing. 
Now I was asked to split the project into two workbooks so it can run in separate instances, on separate monitors. 
Currently, I have the files split, but when I try to run the macro (after changes to reflect the separate instances), I get no errors but I also do not get the effect of the macros reflected across the instances.

The process is meant to be:

1. Find instance with second sheet
2. Assign sheet from second instance to variable "map"
3. Click button in "data"
4. See effect in map

I used to get errors when trying to find the other instance but after googling for a while, found what I think is the solution (the Debug.Print shows the right name), but nothing happens in "map" when the macro is run.

Comment: which macro? And how is that macro launched?

Comment: Macro is associated with a button on the "data" sheet. The snippet provided is the very start of said macro. I know for a fact that the functionality of the macro itself is all good. It's the splitting of files which has brought on problems. The only thing that the macros requires is to be able to access and modify the sheets between the two instances by doing map.activate and data.activate. This is what seems to not e working properly. I do not run into this problem when the two sheets run in the same instance.

Comment: Without having any idea of what the macro does, I'm almost sure that the problem is due to those `Activate` and `ActiveThing` stuff. All I can advice with the available information is to get rid of those and work with explicit sheet references.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194543/excel-process-stuck-in-task-manager-after-code-clean-up/42196345#42196345

Comment: following @A.S.H. piece of advice you could refactor your "Macro" to accept `map` as a worksheet object parameter and use it throughout the "Macro" instead of any _ActiveStuff_